# MySQL return row where x child rows in SAME TABLE match field in first row

Tags: php, mysql

Have table 'posts':

```
-------------------------------------------------
|   id   |   name  |   url  | parentid |  type  |
-------------------------------------------------
|   1    | barname |  NULL  |   NULL   |  bar   |
-------------------------------------------------
|   2    |   NULL  |  beer  |    1     |  drink |
-------------------------------------------------
|   3    |   NULL  |  wine  |    1     |  drink |
-------------------------------------------------
```

Need to get row(parent row) where type = 'bar', and join rows(children) where type = 'drink' and 'parentid' = 'id'.

Desired result:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   id   |  name   |   url  | parentid |  type  | matchedurl1 | matchedurl2 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1    | barname |  NULL  |   NULL   |   bar  |    beer     |    wine     | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Children rows need to be of a variable number. 
(Ie. result needs to have x matchedurl fields depending upon how many child rows found).

Thank you.

Comment: If the number of matched columns be variable, then you are going to need some dynamic SQL for that.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a table pivot issue, and have to use dynamic sql:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SET @cnt = 0;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN c.url = ''',
      c.url,
      ''' THEN c.url ELSE NULL END) AS matchedurl',
      @cnt := @cnt + 1
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM posts p
JOIN posts c
ON p.type = 'bar'
AND c.type = 'drink'
;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT p.*, ', @sql,
                  ' FROM posts p
                  JOIN posts c
                  ON p.type = ''bar''
                  AND c.type = ''drink''
                  AND p.id = c.parentid
                  GROUP BY p.`id`');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[<kbd>**Demo Here**</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53e1d22/13)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option you can try which replaces the variable number of matched columns with a CSV list of matches:

```
SELECT t1.*, COALESCE(t2.matches, 'NA')
FROM posts p1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT parentid, GROUP_CONCAT(url) AS matches
    FROM posts
    WHERE parentid IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY parent_id
) p2
    ON p1.id = p2.parent_id
WHERE p1.parentid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
select p1.*, group_concat(p2.url) as matchedurl from posts p1
join posts p2 on p2.parentid=p1.id
group by parentid
```

The results will have a `matchedurl` column that concatenates your results to look like `beer,wine`

[**Live demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53e1d22/16)

Then in PHP, you can parse the results into an array of matches:

```
$matchedUrls = explode(',', $row['matchedurl'];
```